# Thymeleaf templates does not resolve property

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I need to use Thymeleaf templates for email sending for different locales.

I have next part in my HTML

```
<p th:text="#{TEST}"></p>
```

I have next code

```
    Context context = new Context();
    context.setLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
    String emailBody = templateEngine.process( "WELCOME", context);
```

I have next beans

```
 @Bean
public TemplateEngine mailTemplateEngine() {
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(mailTemplateResolver());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
    templateEngine.setMessageResolver(messageResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ITemplateResolver mailTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/email/common/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF_8.name());
    templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public IMessageResolver messageResolver() {
    return new StandardMessageResolver();
}
```

I am using next dependencies

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have resource bundle messages in "resources" folder for every language I need.
And if you check #{TEST} from my html with ctrl+left click you can see that it sees property files, so IDEA can resolve it.

By when I am running my app and trying to send email I got next result

> ??TEST_de??

And I got similar result for every other language.

How to fix this ? I need TemplateEngine to be capable to get proper property value depending on locale.

Comment: This might help you - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization

Comment: Use the `SpringTemplateEngine` it will automatically get the Spring based `MessageSource`.

Comment: SpringTemplateEngine is not my option. When I am trying to use it there a lot of errors during redirect action in startup stage Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [redirect], template might not exist or might....

Comment: @M.Deinum Please write your answer as a post. I'll choose it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Spring and Thymeleaf you are probably better of using the Thymeleaf classes that offer Spring integration. Like the [`SpringTemplateEngine`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring5/3.0.12.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/spring5/SpringTemplateEngine.html), which will connect with a Spring [`MessageSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) automatically.

Now when using Spring you also might want to utilize the [`SpringResourceTemplateResolver`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring5/3.0.12.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/spring5/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver.html) as well.

```java
@Bean 
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
  ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
  source.setBasename("classpath:/messages");
  return source;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine mailTemplateEngine() {
  SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
  templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(mailTemplateResolver());
  templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
  return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver mailTemplateResolver() {
  SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
  templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/email/common/");
  templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
  templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF_8.name());
  templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);
  templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
  return templateResolver;
}
```

**Pro Tip:** When using Java config try to be as specific as possible in your return type, this makes it easier for Spring to determine callbacks like `ApplicationAware`, `MessageSourceAware` etc. etc.